# MemSQL - populate a table using comma separate string value

Tags: singlestore

I need to pass a list of values to a MemSQL procedure. 
Is there a way of transforming the comma separated integer values from the input string into a table.

Answer (score 1):

MemSQL doesn't yet have something like the python string `split` function that converts a delimited string into an array of strings.  In MemSQL 6.5, the best method would be to do something like this using the `locate` builtin function.

```
delimiter //
create or replace procedure insert_split_string(input text, d text) as
declare
    position int = 1;
    newPosition int = -1; 
begin
    while newPosition != 0 loop
        newPosition = locate(d, input, position);
        if newPosition != 0 then
            insert into t values(substring(input, position, newPosition - position));
            position = newPosition + 1;
        end if; 
    end loop;

    -- Add the last delimited element
    insert into t values(substring_index(input, d, -1));
end //
delimiter ;

create table t(i int);
call insert_split_string("1,2,3,4,5", ",");
select * from t;
```